C# default interface methods combined with base class
When defining a C# interface, we can specify a default implementation. We can normally still implement the method in our class to replace it, but why does that not work after a base class is introduced in-between? There are several things going on here, which I don't understand and did not expect, so I hope someone can explain what exactly is happening here.
Here's an example - both assertions succeed, so depending on the static type, different methods are called.
private interface IFunny
{
    void TryToCallMe() { }
}

private class BaseFunny : IFunny;

private class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny
{
    public void TryToCallMe() => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

[Fact]
public void FunStuff()
{
    ((Action)(() => new DerivedFunny().TryToCallMe())).Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>();
    ((Action)(() => ((IFunny)new DerivedFunny()).TryToCallMe())).Should().NotThrow<InvalidOperationException>();
}

And a follow-up question: When I change the DerivedFunny declaration like this,
public void IFunny.TryToCallMe() => throw new InvalidOperationException();

the compiler gives an error actually claiming that DerivedFunny does not implement the interface IFunny (which I think it should, as its base class does so).
Finally, I can redefine it like this:
private class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny, IFunny
{
    public void TryToCallMe() => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

which seems kind of redundant (unless that compiler error is true). With that implementation, the second assertion will now actually fail and the exception be thrown as well. That's the behaviour I initially would have expected (aka this makes it "work for me"), but I would still prefer to understand why.

My use of "private classes" is limited to entries in local dictionaries; only because I can't think of any other uses. The rest of my classes are internal or public.

You can't make an explicit interface implementation public.

question is not really a duplicate - there was no default interface implementation in the proposed question...

It is not a duplicate. Referenced question has nothing to do with default interface implementation.

@Frank: Can you vote to reopen the question? I posted one vote. I think we need two of them.

Derived classes do not really implement the interfaces of their base classes. Normally, the base class must create an implementation which it can mark as virtual, so that the derived class can override it. In any case, it is creating a new virtual slot id in its method table that remains the same in the derived class method table. In our case, the base class must not and in this case does not create such a slot because the runtime can fallback on the default impl. which the interface itself provides. No slot - no way for the derived type to inject its "interface impl.".

Does this answer your question? Overriding interface default implementation in derived class

@Frank I think I've answered the why as best as I could...would welcome comments from you for what's not understandable.

This happens because DerivedFunny.TryToCallMe is not a method which implements/takes part in IFunny.TryToCallMe dispatch hierarchy, you will get the same behavior with implicit implementation in the intermediate class:
private interface IFunny
{
    void TryToCallMe();
}

private class BaseFunny : IFunny
{
    void IFunny.TryToCallMe(){}
}

BaseFunny will implement the interface and it does not provide options to override this implementation (if you change explicit implementation in BaseFunny then compiler even will hint a bit with the "hides" warnings).
As a workaround in both cases you can:

make the BaseFunny.TryToCallMe virtual and override it in the DerivedFunny

private class BaseFunny : IFunny
{
     public virtual void TryToCallMe()
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

private class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny
{
    public override void TryToCallMe() => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}


"Explicitly" implement the interface in the DerivedFunny:

private class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny, IFunny
{
    public void TryToCallMe() => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}



We can normally still implement the method in our class to replace it,
but why does that not work after a base class is introduced in-between?

Because having default implementation of interfaces finally broke the illusion that interfaces participate in the class inheritance hierarchy, they work in parallel with lots of support from the runtime and the compiler.
Before the addition of default interface implementations interfaces were deceivingly similar to abstract base classes. Let's add an AbstractBaseFunny and pretend that IFunny is just doing the same but less verbose.
public interface IFunny {
    // public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance void
    // identical as the abstract base class
    void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl(); // really abstract
}

public abstract class AbstractBaseFunny {
    //public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance void
    // identical as the interface
    public abstract void TryToCallmeAbstract();
}

public class BaseFunny : AbstractBaseFunny, IFunny {
    //public final hidebysig virtual instance void
    // no newslot - because we reuse the slot in the inheritance method table
    // from the abstract class
    public override sealed void TryToCallmeAbstract() {
    }

    //public final hidebysig **newslot** virtual instance void
    // newslot because the interface that we implement
    // doesn't have ITS slots in the inheritance method table
    public void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl() {
    }
}

public class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny {
    //public hidebysig instance void
    // really just an instance method that is HIDING
    // compiler warning
    public void TryToCallmeAbstract() {
    }

    //public hidebysig instance void
    // really just an instance method that is HIDING
    // compiler warning
    public void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl() {
    }
}

I've also added IL that demonstrate that the method declarations are almost identical with one crucial difference - the newslot modifier. More on that in a bit.
At the end of the hierarchy in DerivedFunny we have the same result, two methods that hide the implementations of BaseFunny and both get warnings for this. This is due to BaseFunny marking those methods as final or sealed in c# - explicitly in the case of AbstractBaseFunny and implicitly in the case of IFunny.
But if we wanted to, we could make them provide their own implementations by removing the sealed modifier for the AbstractBaseFunny method and explicitly adding virtual for IFunny's method.
public class BaseFunny : AbstractBaseFunny, IFunny {
    //public hidebysig virtual instance void
    public override void TryToCallmeAbstract() {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }

    //public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void
    public virtual void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl() {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

then we modify DerivedFunny:
public class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny {
    //public hidebysig virtual instance void
    public override void TryToCallmeAbstract() {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }

    //public hidebysig virtual instance void
    public override void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl() {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

Testing confirms that we did what we wanted to:
IFunny interfaceReference = new DerivedFunny();
interfaceReference.TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl(); // Derived

AbstractBaseFunny abstractClassReference = new DerivedFunny();
abstractClassReference.TryToCallmeAbstract(); // Derived

Let's continue our example with default interface implementation:
public interface IFunny {
    
    // .. other method same as before
    
    //public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void
    // still identical to abstract class
    void TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault() { Console.WriteLine("Interface"); } // really virtual
}

public abstract class AbstractBaseFunny {
    // .. other method same as before

    //public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void
    // still identical to interface
    public virtual void TryToCallMeAbstractDefault() { Console.WriteLine("Abstract"); } // really virtual
}

Now the mental model of interfaces just being convenient abstract classes with multiple-inheritance powers breaks. We cannot do the same thing with interfaces that we can with abstract base classes - we cannot override the default interface implementation if there is a class in the middle ( save for explicitly declaring support for the interface via :IFunny but that will break the mental model too)
// your first try which will just add a new method
// unrelated to the Interface 
// without method hiding errors as in the first example
// so you'd think that you just implemented the interface
// with c# being helpful in emitting the extra IL
public void TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault() { Console.WriteLine("Derived"); }

//CS0115 'DerivedFunny.TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault()': no suitable method found to override
public override void TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault() { Console.WriteLine("Derived"); }

public override void TryToCallMeAbstractDefault() { Console.WriteLine("Derived"); }

The second way I added myself to explicitly override the default interface implementation as I would have with the abstract class. It produced an error which hints at how DerivedFunny really "implemented" IFunnyin our first example:
'DerivedFunny.TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault()': no suitable method found to override

It did so simply by overriding BaseFunny's virtual methods, i.e. indirectly implementing the IFunny interface (with still a bit of runtime assistance that will be made clear shortly).
A very simplified version of how virtual methods work is that each type has a list of methods saved in a table. To achieve polymorphism via the class inheritance hierarchy the runtime structures the creation of this table in the following order:

Virtual methods of base classes
Virtual methods introduced in this class
Instance methods

So when we declare a virtual method in a class with newslot (as we did above) we assign it essentially the next available "id" (e.g. 5 slots from base classes, ours will get id #6). This helps us achieve polymorphism because the index or the slot of the virtual method remains the same across the hierarchy, so the compiler can emit the same method dispatch call code by having the same offset (slot id).
On top of that we have interfaces which have their own dispatch mechanism which changed over the years but for our purpose can be simplified as follows:
The runtime constructs for each class that directly implements an interface an additional table for each of the class' interfaces where the order of the method slots is always same (similarly to how it's the same for virtual methods). Notice that we had newslot in the method declarations of the interface too - this is what includes methods in this table. If we defined a simple instance method in IFunny with sealed, it won't be part of this table.
So for example with IFunny, TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl gets #1, TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault gets #2 in this table. Then the runtime populates BaseFunny's version of this table, with #1 pointing to e.g. #5, and #2 pointing to e.g. #6  slot numbers from its own virtual method table).
Each class that doesn't directly implement an interface but "inherits" it through its base class just receives through the runtime the populated interface table of the parent. If it wants it can explicitly implement the interface by asking the runtime to populate a new table with new values for the slot indexes (e.g. #7 and #8) - not reusing the slots of the base class (#5 and #6).
So in our no default implementation example, DerivedFunny was able to "implement" the interface just by overriding the method i.e. by reusing the slot #5 that BaseFunny first created via newslot:
// BaseFunny
//public hidebysig **newslot** virtual instance void -> #5 slot
public virtual void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl() {
    Console.WriteLine("Base");
}
 
// DerivedFunny
//public hidebysig virtual instance void -> reuse #5 slot
public override void TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl() {
    Console.WriteLine("Derived");
}

It got the same interface table for IFunny from BaseFunny with the mapping of #1 to #5. So, we can say that it just piggybacked off of classical polymorphism to provide the implementation.
In the default implementation example, however, BaseFunny didn't declare a new slot in the virtual table (so there is no #6 really). It just let the runtime populate #2 of IFunny with IFunnys default implementation somehow automatically. Now BaseFunny and DerivedFunny both have the same interface table:

#1 points to #5 in the virtual method table (two different implementations for each but same slot)
#2 points to the default implementation

So DerivedFunny has no way of injecting its implementation for #2 because there is no #6 virtual method slot to reuse. Only thing to do is to explicitly implement the interface and get a its own brand new interface table and populate it with the slot of the new method it will declare.
public class DerivedFunny : BaseFunny, IFunny {
    //.method public final hidebysig **newslot** virtual instance void -> slot #6
    public void TryToCallMeInterfaceDefault() { Console.WriteLine("Derived"); }

Again c# compiler helps obfuscate that we are declaring a virtual method as it did with the declaration of BaseFunny's implementation of TryToCallMeInterfaceNoImpl which got the #5 slot.
As that's the first virtual method DerivedFunny itself declares as newslot (we ignore the ones from the abstract class to simplify matters a bit), it will receive the next slot id #6.
#5 will still make it as #1 for the interface table as it did for BaseFunny, but now #6 will be written in the slot #2 for DerivedFunny's new version of the interface table instead of the default interface implementation.

If you're trying to see which methods get called, I wouldn't do
throw new InvalidOperationException();

but rather something like
Console.WriteLine("Base TryToCallMe");

or it's equivalent.
But, to your question:
try making the method virtual in your base class, and override it in your derived class.
Also, keep in mind that what is called is also based on the type you declare, i.e. whether you are working with your declared interface type, the base type, or derived type.

I wasn't just trying to see which gets called. The exception was used to be able to define the automated test. And I would like to understand the why, not get a workaround of the sort "try this".
